# AWS DynamoDB-Data-Mapper NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am planning to use AWS Dynamo-Data-Mapper for ORM mapping while creating lambda functions in NodeJS with DynamoDB storage. This library is still under developer preview. Does anyone has experience in using this library and is there a risk of using this library since it is still under developer preview? Is there any other better NodeJS library to use for ORM with Dynamo DB.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I code in Java, and the Java [DynamoDBMapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html) is the best DynamoDB SDK by a distance. It provides object modelling, optimistic locking and more. The only other supported high level SDK at the moment is the [.Net Object Persistence Model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKHighLevel.html), which is frankly not even close to being as good as DynamoDBMapper.

If you are using Lambda I personally wouldn't use Java, the functions take too long to run.

The AWS supported [Javascript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.JavaScript.html) does not provide object modelling.

I've seen a few projects that try and fill the gap for a Javascript DynamoDB object mapping SDK, such as [dynamoose](https://dynamoosejs.com/api) and [dynogels](https://github.com/clarkie/dynogels). Personally I wouldn't use these as you simply end up losing functionality offered by DynamoDB. But I'm sure they are good in some circumstances, like prototyping applications rapidly.

I must admit I've not used the new [AWS dynamodb-data-mapper](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-data-mapper-js) (Javascript Object SDK). However its being developed by AWS and its [pretty clear they are serious about it](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/introducing-the-amazon-dynamodb-datamapper-for-javascript-developer-preview/).

Clearly using the SDK depends on your project and appetite to risk. I get a huge amount of value using DynamoDBMapper (the equivalent Java SDK). My code is massively more clean and simple than it would be in a low level SDK.

Comment: "its pretty clear they are serious about it."


Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the case anymore. It's a bit of a mess handling this right now